# Migrating Team Site from OnPrem to SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, migration, sharepoint-on-prem

I've been trying to get whole site migrated from OnPrem environment to SPO, using following instructions:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt210445.aspx#PrepContentPackage
OR
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nishants/2015/07/18/using-windows-powershell-cmdlets-for-sharepoint-online-o365spo-migration/
 (both written very well)

What I did not use from the instructions is -ItemUrl switch (as it is not required in Export-SP and I wanted whole site instead of single library/list) to get the whole site and exporting the package was successful.

I got stuck on the ConvertTo-SPOMigrationTargetedPackage. Which on the other hand to function requires -TargetDocumentLibraryPath switch. 
Obviously this way I am not able to go further if I would like to get the whole site prepared to be migrated...

I really am out of ideas what could be done to make this work - if anything can be done using this method, the way I would like to use it. Hopefully I am only missing something.

Maybe someone would have an advice or any other method on how to move whole site(s) from OnPrem to SPO (not thinking about drive shipping here).

Thanks!

Comment: I would honestly recommend a third party tool and an Azure storage subscription.

Comment: Thanks for response. Even using the methods above I still would need Azure sub... Any recommendation on the third-party tool?

Comment: We used Metalogix and it was pretty good, a vendor we worked with used Sharegate and it was equally good. Look at their offerings and see what will work for you. There is so much that goes into a migration to SPO, it is worth the money paying for a tool instead of doing it all yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You may also get help from this blog for migrating SharePoint on-premises to SharePoint Online natively, which involves usage of Azure Storage: http://sharepoint-content-migration.blogspot.in/2016/05/a-4-step-guide-for-migrating-sharepoint.html

Comment: You can add some brief description from the link. Links may break in long run.